# Align div inside a flex to the right

Tags: html, css

How do I align the album cover `div` to the right inside the card. I tried with `align-self: end` property but that does not seem to work. Could anyone please help?

```css
.card {
  border: 1px red solid;
  width: 450px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.image {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  align-self: end;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div>
    <div>Music controls</div>
  </div>
  <div class="image">Album Cover</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `justify-content: space-between;` to your card's css:

```css
.card {
  border: 1px red solid;
  width: 450px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.image {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  align-self: end;
  border: 1px solid green;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div>
    <div>Music controls</div>
  </div>
  <div class="image">Album Cover</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Flex has two main axis, if you want to align the album cover to the right in the main axis, you need to use the property `justify-content: space-between;` that will expand your music controls and album cover, with `space-between` ittems are evenly distributed in the line; first item is on the start line, last item on the end line, you can check more about [flex here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 1):

- I added a new class to the music controls and added a `flex-grow` value of `2` and `align-self` value of `flex-start`.
- then for `.image`, i added `align-self` value of `flex-end`
- at the end, i removed the hard-coded width/ height from `image`

Good luck!

```css
.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: #005792;
  width: 450px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;  
}

.music-controls{
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 2;
}

.image {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: #fd5f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="music-controls">
    <div>Music controls</div>
  </div>
  <div class="image">Album Cover</div>
</div>
```